# NodeJS establecer un campo Date solo con el patron ('YYYY/MM/DD') en un Schema de MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Pretendo que mi **Schema** `Usuarios` que muestro a continuacion .. :

```
const usuariosSchema = new Schema({
     nombre: String,
     apel_1: String,
     apel_2: String,
     email:String,
     fecha_nacimiento: Date
});
```

.. tenga el campo `fecha_nacimiento: Date` con formato `YYYY/MM/DD` porque del modo en el que esta me guarda datos tales como : `2019-04-11T00:00:00.000Z` y quiero que se **guarde en la base de datos** asi : `2019/04/11`

Comment: MongoDB usa `ISODate` para almacenar los datos tipo `Date`. No podrás almacenar sólo lo que deseas. Pero puedes transformar los datos cuando realices tus consultas. A veces he visto que separan en campos diferentes las fechas, usando un tipo Number para almacenar el día, el mes, y el año en campos separados. Pero si deseas apegarte a tu formato, entonces usa un tipo `String` y realiza las validaciones necesarias antes de un `insert` para que se respete el formato. De resto, no hay manera que almacenes un tipo Date tal como lo planteas.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo que se tiene un problema entre el Frontend y el Backend, de acuerdo a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253415/angular-poner-en-un-input-de-tipo-date-un-valor-que-obtengo-de-mongodb-mediante) pregunta formulada por el O.P. recientemente. Usaré esta solución (no es la única), para evitar tantos pasos del lado Cliente y a la vez evitar dolores de cabeza *parseando* fechas, además aprovecho de mostrar un poco el uso de propiedades muy ventajosas de Mongoose.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea tratar con un valor tipo `Date` en un documento almacenado en la base de datos (MongoDB), de tal manera que al realizar una inserción y luego una petición de dicho valor el formato devuelto sea siempre: "dd/mm/yyyy".

A su vez, se desea usar esa fecha (devuelta con dicho formato), como `value` de un elemento `input` de tipo `date`.

Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date): el formato aceptado como válido para el valor de un elemento `input` de tipo `date`, es el especificado en el estándar [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) que corresponde a: `yyyy-mm-dd`. Entonces, lo que haremos es devolver la fecha de acuerdo a esa especificación.

[image: Documentación oficial del elemento Input de tipo Date]

**SOLUCIÓN**

Dado que se usa un [Stack MEAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle)), vamos a usar el potencial de Mongoose. En particular usaremos una propiedad de la clase ***Schema*** llamada [virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals).

Básicamente un campo `virtual`, es una propiedad de un documento que podemos establecer y luego obtener, pero que no será persistida en nuestra base de datos. De allí el nombre de *virtual*.

Como expliqué en mi comentario, MongoDB almacena las fechas usando el formato [ISODate](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Por lo tanto, cuando deseamos consultar una fecha almacenada en nuestra BD, el resultado obtenido será algo como: `ISODate("2019-04-10T20:21:28.063Z")`.

La idea es poder establecer un campo llamado `fecha_nacimiento` en un documento. El valor de dicha fecha debe tener el siguiente formato: `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Tal vez nos veamos tentados a usar un simple:

```
let fecha = user.fecha_nacimiento.substring(0,10);
```

y problema resuelto. Sin embargo, el campo `fecha_nacimiento` es tipo `Date`, y tratar de hacer un `substring()` nos arrojará un lindo error.

Tendríamos que convertir el valor `Date` en `String`.

Dado que el tipo `Date` tiene un método llamado `toString()` podríamos usarlo de la siguiente manera, pero esto nos devolvería un bonito:

```
> user.fecha_nacimiento.toString();
> "Wed Apr 10 2019 22:22:55 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
```

que tampoco nos sirve.

En realidad el método que buscamos es [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), que nos devolverá algo parecido a esto:

```
> user.fecha_nacimiento.toISOString();
> "2019-04-10T20:22:55.201Z"
```

Entonces podemos aplicar el método `substring()` de la siguiente forma:

```
> user.fecha_nacimiento.toISOString().substring(0,10);
> "2019-04-10"
```

Y ahora si ya tenemos el resultado deseado.

Dicho esto, implementaremos un campo virtual en nuestro *Schema* de Mongoose. Usaremos el método `set` del campo virtual para almacenar la fecha recibida en la base de datos, y el método `get` que nos devolverá la fecha almacenada en el formato deseado.

Nuestro archivo ***user.model.js*** podría quedar así: (ES5)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nombre: String,
  apel_1: String,
  apel_2: String,
  email:String,
  fecha_nacimiento_iso: Date  // he cambiado el nombre del atributo para diferenciarlo del campo virtual
});

// Establecemos un campo virtual
UserSchema.virtual('fecha_nacimiento')
  .set(function(fecha) {
    // El formato esperado es 'yyyy-mm-dd' que es el devuelto por el campo input
    // el valor recibido se almacenará en el campo fecha_nacimiento_iso de nuestro documento
    this.fecha_nacimiento_iso = new Date(fecha);
  })
  .get(function(){
    // el valor devuelto será un string en formato 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    return this.fecha_nacimiento_iso.toISOString().substring(0,10);
  });

// Ya podemos exportar el modelo
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Con esto ya tenemos una forma de darle el formato a la fecha. Es una manera elegante de realizar la tarea. Pero lo mejor de todo es que para el FrontEnd es transparente. Todo se define en el modelo. Solo debemos asegurarnos de recibir los datos correctamente.

Cuando se inserta un nuevo usuario, los datos que se reciben han de contener un atributo llamado `fecha_nacimiento`, con el formato especificado.

Si dicha fecha viene desde un elemento `input` de tipo `date`, el formato está garantizado. Por lo que no se requiere hacer nada del lado Cliente para enviar la información correcta al Servidor.

Ahora, del lado Servidor se debe implementar la forma de devolver los datos al Cliente, de tal manera que incluya el valor devuelto por el campo virtual.

En la [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253415/angular-poner-en-un-input-de-tipo-date-un-valor-que-obtengo-de-mongodb-mediante) dice que se desea mostrar el valor de fecha de nacimiento en un elemento `input` de tipo `date`.

Sin embargo, si enviamos directamente el objeto `user` al cliente, estaremos enviando el campo `fecha_nacimiento_iso`, la cual contiene la fecha en un formato que no deseamos. Por lo tanto debemos construir nuestro propio objeto `usr` con los valores que deseamos enviar al cliente.

En este caso, no deseamos enviar el campo `fecha_nacimiento_iso` sino que deseamos enviar nuestro campo *virtual*, ya que el mismo contiene la fecha en el formato adecuado.

Debo hacer una acotación, en estos momentos (11-Abr-2019) no todos los navegadores [soportan](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input#Compatibilidad_de_navegadores) el elemento `input` de tipo `date`.

Una forma de enviar la información al Cliente sería la siguiente, (supongamos que este es nuestro controlador):

***user.controller.js***

```
const read = (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;
  if(!userId) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'No id'
    });
  }
  User.findById(userId)
    .exec((err, user) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          error: 'Server error: ' + err.message
        });
      }
      if(!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          err: 'No user find with id: ' + userId
        });
      }
      // creamos el objeto que enviaremos al front
      let usr = {};
      usr._id = user._id;  // llenamos los campos que deseamos enviar
      usr.nombre = user.nombre;
      usr.apel1 = user.apel1;
      usr.apel2 = user.apel2;
      usr.email = user.email;
      usr.fecha_nacimiento = user.fecha_nacimiento; // <= Aqui estamos usando el campo virtual
      return res.status(200).json(usr); // <= enviamos 'usr' al front
    });
}
```

Con esto ya tenemos el resultado esperado. Sin complicarnos la vida en *frontend* y tampoco en el *backend*. Todo gracias a la propiedad *virtuals* de Mongoose.

Dejo las siguientes capturas donde se puede apreciar el resultado de esta implementación.

Aquí se aprecia una consulta desde Postman, usando el método descrito en mi respuesta. Se envía un objeto `usr` con los campos deseados al cliente:

[image: Ejemplo de consulta con Postman]

Aquí se aprecia lo que se almacena en la base de datos MongoDB (he resaltado el campo `f_nacimiento` que es de tipo `ISODate`):

[image: Documento almacenado en MongoDB]

De esta manera el problema queda resuelto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tan valiosa respuesta, no la habia visto. Afortunadamente veo que mongoose tiene arreglos para esas cosas