# Angular poner en un input de tipo date un valor que obtengo de mongodb mediante nodejs

Tags: angular, date, angular5, webforms

Ya que **MongoDB** no admite **patrones** a la hora de guardar las **fechas** me veo obligado a hacer las modificaciones en la capa de la **vista**.

Expongo mi **problematica:**

Tengo un `input` de tipo `date`:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha_nacimiento"  
[(ngModel)]="fechaParseada" (change)="mostrar($event)">
```

> El tipo de **inputs** que tiene un **calendario pequeño** para elegir la fecha
>   directamente, todo mucho mas comodo y seguro

El cual recibe de **nodejs** un objeto `usuario` con un campo `fecha_nacimiento` de tipo `Date` ya que no puedo crear un patron en el **modelo** lo tendre que hacer en la **vista**.

Esta es la **funcion** que obtiene el **usuario** :

```
 this.usuarioService.get(this.id_a_buscar).subscribe(
        data =>{
         if (data["status"] == 200) {
            this.user = data['usuario'];
            this.encontrado = true;
            this.editable = false;

            //let str_fecha = this.user.fecha_nacimiento.toString().split('T')[0];
            let date:Date = new Date(this.user.fecha_nacimiento);

            console.log('TIPO USER.FECHA_NACIMIENTO: '+ date+ " === "+typeof date);
            this.fechaParseada.setDate(date.getDate() );
            this.fechaParseada.setMonth(date.getMonth());
            this.fechaParseada.setFullYear(date.getFullYear());



            console.log('FECHA PARSEADA => '+date)
         }

         if (data["status"] != 200){
          alert(data['message'])
          this.user = {_id:"",nombre:"",apel_1:"",apel_2:"",email:"",fecha_nacimiento:new Date};
          this.encontrado = false;
          this.editable = false;
         }

        }
      );
```

en la funcion recojo la `fecha_nacimiento` por separado porque estoy intentando parsearlo de alguna manera que lo entienda el `input`  de tipo `date` ya que , en vez de ponerme la fecha, me esta poniendo el `input default` de `dd/mm/aaaa` como si **no entendiera la fecha que le estoy pasando** .

**¿Como podria resolver este problema de parseos de fechas?**

Me gustaria aclarar que con un `input` de tipo `datetime` se arregla todo, pero claro, pierde todo el tema de **elegirlo por el calendario** y la seguridad que da el otro, aparte de que se ve el tema de :  `T00:00:00.....`

Comment: Puedes leer [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253375/nodejs-establecer-un-campo-date-solo-con-el-patron-yyyy-mm-dd-en-un-schema-d/253532#253532) respuesta que publiqué en tu pregunta anterior. Creo que sería una forma de resolver el problema, además te hago unas acotaciones sobre el elemento `input` de tipo `date`. Saludos

Comment: Cuando trabajas con el ng-model y las fechas en el input tipo Date necesitas convertir de manera manual al formato yyyy/MM/dd. Después el mismo navegador dependiendo del lenguaje que tiene el usuario lo convertirá a la fecha que usa(dd/MM/yyyy) Por eso es que el html del navegador interpreta con el valor de default.